# Creating grid after merging shapefiles?

Tags: pyqgis, merge, vector-grid

Follow up question to [QGIS Model Builder Script - Possible to merge layers in a folder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97392/qgis-model-builder-script-possible-to-merge-layers-in-a-folder)

I think I'm missing something very obvious here but can't seem to find it. After merging shapefiles in a folder, I would like a grid to be created. However, I am unsure how to call the result of the merged file into the grid function.

```
## Test=name
## Select_Directory=folder
## cellsize=number 1000
## grid=output vector

import os
import glob


os.chdir(Select_Directory)
output = glob.glob('./*.shp')
Layer_0 = output[0]

processing.runalg("saga:mergeshapeslayers",  Layer_0, ";".join(output))    
processing.runalg("qgis:creategrid", cellsize, cellsize, 24108, 18351, 258293, 665638, 1, 'EPSG:7405', grid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing already has a tool to create grids from an input layer. I therefore suggest to create a model using your join tool followed by the grid creation tool.